# Rails fields_for pulling model name instead of ID for params id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formbuilder, fields-for

I'm using fields_for to create a page for editing multiple user objects in my app. I've been using this Railscast video as a point of reference. http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually The issue I am running into is that rather than using the user id when generating the html, the form builder is inserting the user's name. I have no idea why. Below is my controller, view, and some of the html generated.

View

```
 Manage Your User Licenses
User License Management for <%= @org.title %>
<%= form_tag update_many_user_licenses_path, :method => :put do %>
  <% for user in @users %>
    <%= fields_for "users[]", user do |user_fields| %>
      <div><%= user.name %></div>
      <div><%= user_fields.label :active_license %>
      <%= user_fields.check_box :active_license %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Mark as Complete" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class UserLicensesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def manage
    @org = current_user.organization
    @users = @org.users
  end
  def update_many
    @users = User.find(params[:users])
    @users.each do |user|
      user.update_attributes!(params[:user].reject { |k,v| v.blank? })
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Updated users licenses."
    redirect_to manage_user_licenses_path
  end
end
```

HTML

```
<div>Tyrel Denison</div>
<div><label for="users_Tyrel-Denison_active_license">Active license</label>
<input name="users[Tyrel-Denison][active_license]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input   id="users_Tyrel-Denison_active_license" name="users[Tyrel-Denison][active_license]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></div>
```

Comment: Try `giving @users = User.find(params[:id])` instead of `@users = User.find(params[:users])` in `update_many`.

Comment: This issue is produced before the update_many. The view I posted is the manage view.

Comment: You're not overriding the `to_param` method in the `User` class, are you? Additionally, can you post the `User`, just so we can see if there's something unusual going on there?

Comment: I agree with @PaulRichter, I think OP use [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method on user model

Comment: You gentlemen are correct. Found this at the bottom of my user model.

      `def to_param`
        `# TODO USe something better than this plz`
        `self.name.gsub(/\s+/, '-')`
      `end`

Looks like the guy I inherited this code base from was using it for linkedin API calls. Any way I can override it in the new controller or somewhere else so as not to break any existing functionality?

Comment: Wow, that's weird. I am not familiar with the linkedin API gem, so is there any way you can simply remove that method override entirely? Ultimately, the problem is that `fields_for` calls `to_params`, and you don't have a choice in that matter. I would honestly be astonished if the linkedin Gem required you to override that method, as it would most definitely break any model that used it, as you experienced (and I can't explain why the other developer decided to do that).

Comment: Other than that, I can't give you more info without seeing more code. I would probably want to see where in the system the user model is being used with the linkedin gem (meaning, in what way is it being used, so we can figure out an alternative). If you want to edit and add anything to the question, and ping me (put an `@` in front of my name without spaces), I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: @PaulRichter Just noticed this was "unresolved". If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to give you answer credit.

Comment: @TyrelDenison Alright, will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the LinkedIn API Gem, based on our discussion, it seems the [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method is being overwritten in your `User` model.

From the comments, this is apparently what your `to_param` method looks like:

```
def to_param  # TODO USe something better than this plz  
    self.name.gsub(/\s+/, '-')  
end
```

You reported that *rather than using the user id when generating the html, the form builder is inserting the user's name*, and as you can see, this is precisely what is happening in that method. Ultimately, `fields_for` calls `to_param`, and you don't have a choice in that matter.

I would be quite astonished that the LinkedIn gem required you to override that method, as it would most definitely break any model that used it, as you experienced (and I can't explain why the other developer decided to do that - it's possible they innocently wrote the method without realizing it already exists in the base class)

I can't give you more detailed information without examining the system more closely, however I would suggestion trying to find how/where `to_param` is being used (assuming it is being called explicitly somewhere), and create a separate method instead.

Comment: I've removed the to_param and have had no lose of function in my linkedin integration. My guess is that this was a part of something done in the early dev stages and was never utilized/fleshed out. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @TyrelDenison Ah there you go. That's certainly possible. Glad I could help.